# How do you insert an ActiveRecord object via rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How may i insert an New Active Record object via Rails console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much create a new object with the required parameters and call `.save` on it.

So say you want to insert a person record and all the person needs is a first and last name, you can just do

`Person.new(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe").save`

Edit: You can also simply do `Person.create(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe")` which creates and saves the record.

More here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html Look at section **5 CRUD: Reading and Writing Data**